# Why H comes in Smiles for the structure on which H is not present

Tags: rdkit

When I read ".mol" file and convert to Smiles using Rdkit, the smiles comes with H, However 'H' are not present in the original .xyz file. Here is the way I did:

```
m3 = Chem.MolFromMolFile('Al_neutral.mol', strictParsing=False)
ms = Chem.MolToSmiles(m3)
mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(ms)
```

When I print 'ms' it is

```
'[Al]12[AlH2]34[Al]5[AlH2]16[Al]1[AlH2]57[Al]5[AlH2]89[Al]3[AlH2]23[Al]8[AlH2]15[Al]46379'
```

Why 'H' are there and how can we interpret these numbers? Please advise me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hydrogens you see in the SMILES are modelled implicitly. Take a look at this [blog post](https://nextmovesoftware.com/blog/2013/02/27/explicit-and-implicit-hydrogens-taking-liberties-with-valence/#:%7E:text=explicit%20when%20it%20comes%20to,associated%20with%20a%20parent%20atom.) for information about implicit and explicit hydrogens. You will notice that if you convert back to a ".mol" representation the hydrogens will not be present:

```
smiles = '[Al]12[AlH2]34[Al]5[AlH2]16[Al]1[AlH2]57[Al]5[AlH2]89[Al]3[AlH2]23[Al]8[AlH2]15[Al]46379'
mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles)
print(Chem.MolToMolBlock(mol))


 RDKit          2D

 13 24  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000
    1.0607    0.0000    0.0000 Al  0  0  0  0  0  3  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -0.0000   -1.0607    0.0000 Al  0  0  0  0  0  6  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -1.0607    0.0000    0.0000 Al  0  0  0  0  0  3  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.0000    1.0607    0.0000 Al  0  0  0  0  0  6  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -1.4230    1.5350    0.0000 Al  0  0  0  0  0  3  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -2.1213   -1.0607    0.0000 Al  0  0  0  0  0  6  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -2.9642    0.1801    0.0000 Al  0  0  0  0  0  3  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.1213   -3.1820    0.0000 Al  0  0  0  0  0  6  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.0607   -2.1213    0.0000 Al  0  0  0  0  0  3  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.1213   -1.0607    0.0000 Al  0  0  0  0  0  6  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.1820   -2.1213    0.0000 Al  0  0  0  0  0  3  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -1.8974    0.1120    0.0000 Al  0  0  0  0  0  6  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -1.0607   -2.1213    0.0000 Al  0  0  0  0  0  6  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  2  1  0
  2  3  1  0
  3  4  1  0
  4  5  1  0
  5  6  1  0
  6  7  1  0
  7  8  1  0
  8  9  1  0
  9 10  1  0
 10 11  1  0
 11 12  1  0
 12 13  1  0
  4  1  1  0
 12  5  1  0
 10  1  1  0
  9  2  1  0
 13 10  1  0
 13  2  1  0
  6  3  1  0
 12  7  1  0
 13  4  1  0
 13  6  1  0
 11  8  1  0
 13  8  1  0
M  END
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I want to use rdkit tool to read get the atomic features from ".mol" data of 3D molecule, for that, I convert it to Smiles as above and use Rdkit  to generate features. I am a little confused is this process reliable or not, because I read somewhere about its application to 2D geometry. If you have any idea, please advise me. Thanks again.

Comment: I still did not understand the meaning of the numbers 12, 34, .. in the Smiles representation. Could you please help me understand this?

Comment: The numbers in the smiles indicate ring closures, the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_molecular-input_line-entry_system) article has a decent explanation. The smiles you have chosen here is a particularly complex example so perhaps not the easiest to understand.

Comment: As for the features, I am a little confused. What sort of features do you want to calculate?

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Yes, the data is pretty complex here. Can we represent 3D inorganic crystals with Smiles? When I read I did not find any explanation about such a point. By features, I mean the entire properties of elements like, atomic number, valences, weights and so on.

Comment: I don't have much/any experience with these kinds of molecules, I don't see why you cannot represent them with smiles, although you will lose all of the 3D information (of course). I do not see why you need to convert them to smiles anyway considering these 2D properties do not take account of the 3D information anyway, just calculate features on the molecule read from the file

Comment: Main thought behind the conversion is to use the existing tool such as RdKIT to extract the related information. I already converted some of them and get the information of atomic properties, as well as bonding information. I just wanted to make sure what I am doing is a reliable. Please, suggest me if there are any other tools to do the same. Thank you so much for your time .

Comment: Seems reasonable to me, just load the molecule from the mol file and then calculate properties directly. No need for smiles. For specific questions about these kinds of molecules you may find better help on the [rdkit mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/rdkit/mailman/rdkit-discuss/).

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate your suggestion. I will use that approach.